# Creating XML using DataSet.WriteXml. How to change the node name?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

Is there any way to change the `DataSet` default node name? I am creating XML from a `DataTable`.

This is my code:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Products");
dataSet.Tables.Add(tbl);
dataSet.WriteXml(@"D:\Temp\test.xml");
```

This is the XML I'm getting:

```
 <Products>
    <Table1>
      <product_name>McWilliams Hanwood Chardonnay 750mL</product_name>      
      <id>121385</id>
      <price>7.60</price>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        ...
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        ...
    </Table1>
</Products>
```

Is there a way to change `Table1` to `Product` like:

```
<Products>
 <Product>
 ....
 </Product>
  <Product>
 ....
 </Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: I expect that "Table1" is the name of the datatable `tbl`. Looking it up, it would be `tbl.TableName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name that appears is the name of the `DataTable`. You can change its name using the `TableName` property like this:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Products");
tbl.TableName = "Product";
dataSet.Tables.Add(tbl);
dataSet.WriteXml(@"D:\Temp\test.xml");
```

You can also pass the `"Product"` name when you construct the table:

```
var tbl = new DataTable("Product");
```