# Remove table1 keyword from I generation in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

When I am making *XML* then table1 and table2 tage automatically add.
I want to remove this keyword and would be replace by Name keyword
.
Here is my code.

Dim xmlDoc As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("\App_Data\myxml.xml"), False)
            dsMaster.WriteXml(xmlDoc)
            xmlDoc.Close()
            Response.Write("myxml.XML file successfully updated!")

my output is below

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <count>1</count>
    <word>Repair</word>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <count>2</count>
    <word>Repair1</word>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <count>1</count>
    <word>Repair2</word>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <count>2</count>
    <word>Repair3</word>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <count>1</count>
    <word>Repair4</word>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table2>
    <count>27</count>
    <word>Repair5</word>
    <Name>xyz1</Name>
  </Table2>
  <Table2>
    <count>14</count>
    <word>Repair6</word>
    <Name>xyz2</Name>
  </Table2>
  <Table2>
    <count>19</count>
    <word>Repair7</word>
    <Name>xyz3</Name>
  </Table2>
  <Table2>
    <count>14</count>
    <word>Repair8</word>
    <Name>xyz5</Name>
  </Table2>
  <Table2>
    <count>22</count>
    <word>Repair9</word>
    <Name>xyz6</Name>
  </Table2>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: what `Name keyword` you need to use ? name1 for table1 and name2 for table2 or what?

Comment: and show the query that used to fill `dsMaster`

Comment: i just want to remove keyword Table1 and tabl2 which is automatically generated.and i want to replace by name or name2. which is database column

Comment: ok !! that I understood but what I asked is instead of Table1 or Table2 what name you want to give ??

Comment: like DomainName eg. Abc.com,xyz.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating XML using DataSet.WriteXml. How to change the node name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290205/creating-xml-using-dataset-writexml-how-to-change-the-node-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use XML Linq then straight XML.  I little bit tricky but found a simple method.  You have to enumerate from the end of the XML to the beginning to get it to work.  Like all list/array object when enumerating and replacing things go astray if you work forward.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
            "<NewDataSet>" +
              "<Table1>" +
                "<count>1</count>" +
                "<word>Repair</word>" +
                "<Name>abc</Name>" +
              "</Table1>" +
              "<Table1>" +
                "<count>2</count>" +
                "<word>Repair1</word>" +
                "<Name>abc</Name>" +
              "</Table1>" +
              "<Table1>" +
                "<count>2</count>" +
                "<word>Repair3</word>" +
                "<Name>abc</Name>" +
              "</Table1>" +
              "<Table2>" +
                "<count>27</count>" +
                "<word>Repair5</word>" +
                "<Name>xyz1</Name>" +
              "</Table2>" +
              "<Table2>" +
                "<count>14</count>" +
                "<word>Repair6</word>" +
                "<Name>xyz2</Name>" +
              "</Table2>" +
              "<Table2>" +
                "<count>19</count>" +
                "<word>Repair7</word>" +
                "<Name>xyz3</Name>" +
              "</Table2>" +
            "</NewDataSet>";

            XElement ds = XElement.Parse(input);

            List<XElement> table1s =  ds.Descendants("Table1").ToList();
            for(int e = table1s.Count - 1; e >= 0; e--)
            {
                table1s[e].ReplaceWith(new XElement("ABC", table1s[e].Descendants()));
            }
            List<XElement> table2s = ds.Descendants("Table2").ToList();
            for (int e = table2s.Count - 1; e >= 0; e--)
            {
                table2s[e].ReplaceWith(new XElement("XYZ", table2s[e].Descendants()));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that dsMaster is a DataSet, and it consists of two DataTables namely, Table1 & Table2.

You need to rename the DataTable names like:

```
dsMaster.Tables(0).TableName = dsMaster.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name")
dsMaster.Tables(1).TableName = dsMaster.Tables(1).Rows(0)("Name")
```

Although, this will be a very bad implementation. Better you create your structure classes and then serialize them instead of the DataTables.